# MySQL making relations while inserting data into diffrent tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

So I have these tables (I'll simplify the real structure):

```
+----------------+   +----------------+
| CLIPS          |   | AUTHORS        |
+----------------+   +----------------+
| CLIP_ID        |   | AUTHOR_ID (PK) |
| LINK           |   | AUTHOR         |
| AUTHOR_ID (FK) |   | TITLE_ID (FK)  |
| TITLE_ID (FK)  |   +----------------+
| GENRE_ID (FK)  |
+----------------+

+----------------+   +----------------+
| TITLES         |   | GENRES         |
+----------------+   +----------------+
| TITLE_ID (PK)  |   | GENRE_ID (PK)  |
| TITL           |   | GENRE          |
+----------------+   +----------------+
```

How do I make relations while inserting data into these tables (any help is welcome, straight or tutorial links)?

When I insert Michael Jackson into authors, thriller into titles and music clip link into clips, I can have all those records related to (for example) same clip id.

**Example:** clip with id 2312123 is Michael Jackson thriller [link]

Thanks

Comment: Why does `Author` table need a `Title_Id` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you insert the author, title and genre, and retrieve the primary keys for the newly inserted rows. To get the primary keys, something like this might help:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

You then use the primary keys to insert the row into clips. The clips table is dependent on the other tables, so you need to fill them first.

As a further word of advice, database tables should be named in singular (e.g. Author, Clip, etc). A table models an entity.

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful, do you know if it's the only way that modern databases are made?

Comment: The first part: *"First you insert the author, title and genre, ..."* can be tricky. ***"First you insert the author and retrieve the primary key for the newly inserted row or, if the author already exists in your table, you retrieve the existing `author_id`. Then you do the same for title and genre. Then you go and insert in the `clip`..."***

Comment: Well that's the thing, i tought there could be some simpler way to deal with it (i hope), here's example code from one of tables: CREATE TABLE autor
(
    Aut_Id int NOT NULL,
    Nazwa varchar(250),
    Tyt_Id int NOT NULL,
    
    Primary Key (Aut_Id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_TytAutor FOREIGN KEY (Tyt_Id) REFERENCES tytul(Tyt_Id)
);       I tought references could do enough to automaticly deal with this problem, but somehow i don't belive it's that simple

Comment: @Malyo: I'm not sure what you mean by "the only way that modern databases are made". The majority of databases are relational, and that means that tables are interrelated by keys (PK and FK in your question). This in turn means that things get a little bit complicated when querying data (requiring several joins), and also inserting (requiring multiple inserts). But that's a small price to pay for having structured data that you can retrieve and present in whichever way you like.

Comment: Ok to simplify my whole question: how do i make (while inserting) different PK'S appear in one table (as FK ofcourse)that is obviously related to them. Other than the method you gave me few minutes ago (if there's no i think i can handle it tho, just wanna make sure).

Comment: You can't make referential constraints do the work for you. You really have to insert in one table at a time.